# How do I check if two input variables are in the same position in two different lists and return as valid?

Tags: python, list, authentication

I'm trying to create a simple login sequence in terminal but I can't figure out how to check if both the username and the password are in the same position in the list

```
usernames = ['username', 'hello']
passwords = ['password', 'world']

# my code so far:
from getpass import getpass
import time
import logins

username = input('Username: ')
password = input('Password: ')

print('Logging In...')
time.sleep(1)

def check_login(user, pasw):
    if user in logins.users and pasw in logins.passes:
        print('Valid')
    else:
        print('Invalid user and password, try again.')


check_login(username, password)
```

#It works except for the fact that i can input (username, world) or (hello, password)
#I'm trying to check that each username and password are in the same order (0,0, 1,1, etc) and
#return it as valid. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip`:

```
def check_login(user, pasw):
    if (user, pasw) in zip(logins.users, logins.passes):
        print('Valid')
    else:
        print('Invalid user and password, try again.')
```

If you are to call this method repeatedly, it is better to create a `O(1)` lookup structure:

```
lookup = dict(zip(logins.users, logins.passes))

def check_login(user, pasw):
    if lookup.get(user, None) == pasw:
        print('Valid')
    else:
        print('Invalid user and password, try again.')
```

Comment: Why the dv, if I may ask?

Comment: this is faster than @srdg 's answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From what I get about this question, you can just check their indices using `index` inbuilt to lists to assert if both the user and password are at the same location.

```
def check_login(user, pasw):
    if user in logins.users and pasw in logins.passes and logins.users.index(user)==logins.passes.index(pasw):
        print('Valid')
    else:
        print('Invalid user and password, try again.')
```

Comment: thanks! works perfectly and a lot faster than the solution I just came up with.

Comment: If it is working for you, please accept the answer.

Comment: I will, it says I need to wait 4 minutes though.

Comment: This will not work for the second of two users that happen to have the same password.